# jQuery not working offline still after downloading the jQuery library

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have downloaded the jquery library and i put all my html,css and javascript files in the same folder.But its still not working.following is the code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    $('div').fadeOut('slow');
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="x.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

  <body>
    <div>
      <button>good</button>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where do you include your custom JavaScript file ?

Comment: You are missing a closing `</head>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your own js file:

```
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="x.css"/>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="your-js-file.js"></script>
</head>
 <body>
  <div>
   <button>good</button>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to close your head tag:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="x.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <button>good</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```